# How Do I Render A Lot Of Empty Divs As Grid Items In React?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a very large grid where grid items light up when hovered over (Reference [this](https://medium.com/@dailyfire/cursor-trails-3-simple-css-tricks-to-add-to-any-website-part-1-64750798583c) for what I am trying to do).

I need to render 2500 grid items that are all empty divs, how do I do this properly? I considered using map but there is nothing to map considering all the divs are empty.

```
<div className='gridContainer'>
  //render divs here
  <div className='gridItem'/> //first
  ...
  <div className='griditem'/>  //2500th
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to use an empty array to map to these divs. Sth like the following

```
{ Array.from(Array(2500).keys()).map(i => <div key={i} className='gridItem'/>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
const getEmptyDiv(number) => {
const div = "";
for(i = 0; i<number; i++) {
  div.concat('<div className='gridItem'/>');
}
// before returning convert it to string to html 
return div;

}
```